Unity ARFoundation with ARCore Scene Segmentation + ARKit Mesh Classification
Is this possible:
Unity ARFoundation with ARCore Scene Segmentation + ARKit Mesh Classification - both of which are supported by  Unity's ARFoundation Samples
And what's the setup process?
